# what is the best structure of a shop & product like database in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, schema, database

i think there is two type of structure  of shop & product like database

**first**

```
  ShopSchema = new Schema({
     product_ids:[Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  })

   ProductSchema = new Schema({
     product_name:String,
  })
```

**second**

```
  ShopSchema = new Schema({

  })

   ProductSchema = new Schema({
     shop_id:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     product_name:String,
  })
```

the first solution have a clean product collections compared to the second, every document in product's collection hava a shop_id field(kind of wasting space i think),but get all of product via first structure could be painful, whereas second one is pretty easy.

so i was wondering which one is the best. or do u have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself the following question: should you be able to sell same product in multiple shops?

If the answer is no, then you could consider that `shop_id` is a property of the Shop and the second option you gave should be a valid solution.

If the answer is yes, then you need to be able to map a product to multiple shops. If you would use the second design, you would need to duplicate a product object multiple times, once per shop it is sold in, which would equal for a new schema you could call for instance `ProductInShop`.

Note that you still have two very valid options how to model this. Either you 1) add `product_ids` property to `ShopSchema` or 2) add `shop_ids` property to `ProductSchema`.

I'm guessing that by saving space you also mean normalizing the data. Unlike in relational databases, in document databases you generally tend to avoid normalization and instead, de-normalize as much as possible. For example: in relational databases you would typically add this as a new table with columns `shop_id` and `product_id`. In a document database like MongoDB you generally should prefer embedding as much as possible into single documents to avoid "document joins".

Also just a note about Mongoose. If you want to take advantage of Mongoose's [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), please provide additionally an explicit reference to the collection name. For instance:

```
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
   product_ids: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }]
});
```

In such a way you can use Mongoose to e.g. "find all shops and all products that are sold in each shop":

```
Shop.find().populate('product_ids').exec(function (err, shops) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thanx man it really helps a lot . i think i should remember this "In a document database like MongoDB you generally should prefer embedding as much as possible into single documents to avoid "document joins"."

Answer (score 1):

The second version is much more efficient for most use cases. Denormalization is the name of the game with NoSQL persistence solutions. The goal is that get as much of the data you need in as few queries as possible. More often than not this requires duplicating data and deal with the potential headache of having to update a large number of documents when that duplicated data changes.

For example, you might even have to add the shop name to the product document if you wish to display that information on a webpage because if you do not you will still end up having to query the shops collections. Given the fact that shop names do not tend to change that should be relatively headache free but it's those kinds of things you'll have to keep into account when designing your schema. Start with your usecases and work your way down when designing one.